# How to visualize a correlation of one variable to many using the corrplot package in r

Tags: r, visualization, correlation, r-corrplot

I am trying to visualize the correlation of one variable (cl_wet) on 16 other variables in R using the corrplot package. My data does contain a fair amount of NA values, but I have been able to omit them in my correlation code I have used before. It just won't work for the visualization:

Here is the code I have been running:

```
liqcor <- cor(x = liquid.wet$cl_wet, y = liquid.wet[2:17], use = "complete.obs")
corrplot(liqcor)
```

And I have been receiving these errors:

```
Error in symbols(Pos, add = TRUE, inches = FALSE, rectangles = matrix(1, : 
invalid symbol coordinates
```

```
Warning in min(corr, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(corr, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Error in symbols(Pos, add = TRUE, inches = FALSE, rectangles = matrix(1,  : 
  invalid symbol coordinates
```

Any advice is appreciated! Below is a sample of my code for reproducibility

```
liquid.dataset <-
  structure(
    list(
      cl_wet = c(
        0.15738,
        0.07897,
        0.21313,
        0.20552,
        0.21005,
        0.3,
        0.30583,
        0.29432,
        0.22091,
        0.14322,
        0.17247,
        0.29264,
        0.12911,
        0.2439,
        0.32264,
        0.333,
        0.4097,
        0.1386,
        0.25436,
        0.52432,
        0.44101,
        0.20917,
        0.14436,
        0.17538,
        0.13455
      ),
      Moisture = c(
        95,
        98,
        95,
        96,
        95,
        93,
        89,
        91,
        88,
        96,
        96,
        93,
        96,
        91,
        89,
        92,
        88,
        NA,
        NA,
        89,
        89,
        96,
        96,
        96,
        97
      ),
      Dry.matter = c(
        5L,
        2L,
        5L,
        4L,
        5L,
        7L,
        11L,
        9L,
        12L,
        4L,
        4L,
        7L,
        4L,
        9L,
        11L,
        8L,
        12L,
        NA,
        NA,
        11L,
        11L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        3L
      ),
      TN = c(
        0.530443645,
        0.28263789,
        0.512529976,
        0.497601918,
        0.491630695,
        0.666786571,
        0.745407674,
        0.723513189,
        0.980275779,
        0.617026379,
        0.330407674,
        0.719532374,
        0.447841727,
        0.768297362,
        1.062877698,
        0.91558753,
        1.188273381,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.878764988,
        0.860851319,
        0.468741007,
        0.436894484,
        0.371211031,
        0.301546763
      ),
      P2O5 = c(
        0.179856115,
        0.082733813,
        0.179856115,
        0.191846523,
        0.191846523,
        0.167865707,
        0.179856115,
        0.20383693,
        0.383693046,
        0.167865707,
        0.101918465,
        0.287769784,
        0.143884892,
        0.251798561,
        0.419664269,
        0.35971223,
        0.575539568,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.323741007,
        0.35971223,
        0.116306954,
        0.143884892,
        0.131894484,
        0.10911271
      ),
      K2O = c(
        0.275779376,
        0.1558753,
        0.347721823,
        0.323741007,
        0.335731415,
        0.419664269,
        0.431654676,
        0.431654676,
        0.503597122,
        0.347721823,
        0.275779376,
        0.455635492,
        0.251798561,
        0.419664269,
        0.575539568,
        0.575539568,
        0.815347722,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.539568345,
        0.551558753,
        0.383693046,
        0.239808153,
        0.227817746,
        0.287769784
      ),
      Na = c(
        0.065947242,
        0.037170264,
        0.088729017,
        0.082733813,
        0.085131894,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.082733813,
        NA,
        0.049160671,
        0.100719424,
        0.179856115,
        0.179856115,
        0.251798561,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.143884892,
        0.143884892,
        0.088729017,
        0.053956835,
        0.076738609,
        0.088729017
      ),
      Ca = c(
        0.083932854,
        0.049160671,
        0.075539568,
        0.087529976,
        0.086330935,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.080335731,
        NA,
        0.085131894,
        0.09352518,
        0.131894484,
        0.131894484,
        0.167865707,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.112709832,
        0.117505995,
        0.052757794,
        0.073141487,
        0.086330935,
        0.083932854
      ),
      Mg = c(
        0.059952038,
        0.034772182,
        0.07793765,
        0.081534772,
        0.081534772,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.064748201,
        NA,
        0.050359712,
        0.098321343,
        0.119904077,
        0.10911271,
        0.167865707,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.215827338,
        0.227817746,
        0.047961631,
        0.056354916,
        0.080335731,
        0.061151079
      ),
      Zn = c(
        0.028776978,
        0.013189448,
        0.044364508,
        0.044364508,
        0.045563549,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.004916067,
        NA,
        0.029976019,
        0.007074341,
        0.007553957,
        0.006235012,
        0.009952038,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.006594724,
        0.006714628,
        0.013189448,
        0.023980815,
        0.005755396,
        0.001115108
      ),
      Fe = c(
        0.008992806,
        0.004916067,
        0.023980815,
        0.025179856,
        0.026378897,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.01558753,
        NA,
        0.010551559,
        0.00911271,
        0.017985612,
        0.017985612,
        0.022781775,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.013189448,
        0.01558753,
        0.005635492,
        0.008513189,
        0.014388489,
        0.002877698
      ),
      Mn = c(
        0.001918465,
        0.000791367,
        0.003597122,
        0.003717026,
        0.00383693,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.001558753,
        NA,
        0.001798561,
        0.001798561,
        0.003117506,
        0.00323741,
        0.003956835,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.003956835,
        0.004316547,
        0.001318945,
        0.001558753,
        0.001438849,
        0.000683453
      ),
      Cu = c(
        0.003117506,
        0.002398082,
        0.007913669,
        0.008393285,
        0.008633094,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.001558753,
        NA,
        0.002517986,
        0.006354916,
        0.003357314,
        0.002278177,
        0.004796163,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.001558753,
        0.001558753,
        0.001438849,
        0.00383693,
        0.002398082,
        0.000959233
      ),
      S = c(
        0.071942446,
        0.028776978,
        0.106714628,
        0.107913669,
        0.107913669,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.028776978,
        NA,
        0.037170264,
        0.068345324,
        0.131894484,
        0.131894484,
        0.179856115,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.095923261,
        0.094724221,
        0.081534772,
        0.061151079,
        0.034772182,
        0.023980815
      ),
      NH3 = c(
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.851318945,
        0.731414868,
        0.923261391,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA
      ),
      TC = c(
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_,
        NA_real_
      ),
      NO3 = c(
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        0.001318945,
        7.79e-05,
        3.6e-05,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA,
        NA
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, 25L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

Comment: For reproducibility, please provide your data using `dput()`, not by using `print()`.

Comment: @jrcalabrese thank you for pointing that out. Text has been edited with dput of the first 25 rows of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have missing values and the number of missing values are not equal between your features, it is not recommended to use **`complete.obs`** option within the **`cor()`** function because every row containing missing value will be completely removed and you will loose information for some pairwise comparisons that are not missing indeed. Instead, better to use **'`pairwise.complete.obs`'** option where missing values will be removed only a particular pairwise correlation. Thus the correlation or covariance between each pair of variables is computed using all complete pairs of observations on those variables.

```
#calculate correlation
liqcor <- cor(x = liquid.dataset$cl_wet, y =liquid.dataset[2:17], use = "pairwise.complete.obs")

# plot correlation matrix
library(corrplot)
corrplot(liqcor
         ,addgrid.col = T
         ,type = 'upper'
         ,addCoef.col = T
         ,number.cex = .7
         ,diag = T
         ,tl.cex = .9)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @SALAR, this is exactly what I needed. Any reason why "Moisture" was omitted from this output? The last 15 columns are there, just not moisture. Thanks again!

Comment: Dear @mbelumn, the code was edited. The diag should be set to TRUE. now it is fine.